# Object's method is being called, without me ever calling it, when I send it via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple object called `Entry`, which until just recently only had a few basic properties.  During certain events, I would perform REST actions on these objects to an API living in C# code. Until just recently, this worked fine. I would POST or PUT these objects in the body of an AJAX request using my little request service, which ended like so:

```
$.ajax(url, 
{
    type:method,
    headers:headers,
    data:options.data, //there is an instance of Entry in options.data
    timeout: this.timeoutLength
});
```

Recently I added a function to the Entry.

```
function Entry(foo, bar){
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
    this.doStuff = function(){ ... } //added this code
}
```

I added the function, but questioned the user story behind its use again so I switched back to the browser, refreshed, and ran some more tests. Without ever *calling* the function `doStuff` anywhere, it's effects were being seen.

I replaced `doStuff`'s body with a simple alert, and sure enough every time I did something that behind the scenes called an AJAX request with an Entry object, I got my alert message.  Why in the world is this happening? Why is `doStuff` being called without me telling it to?

Comment: Asked and answered at exactly the same time?  What are you, a robot?

Comment: @bpeterson76 Never noticed the "answer your own question, Q&A style" option when posting? In fact, [I believe its encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: I was banging my head over this, so I thought it both interesting and useful to share in case anyone else runs into it

Comment: Consider adding more detail, I have no idea what is going on and what is called. The only thing I can see is `complete` and of course that is called.

Comment: @Esailija thanks for the suggestion. Removed `complete` because it was a red herring, and named the function in question here. Hope its more clear

Comment: Ah I get it now, there is an instance of `Entry` in the `options.data`. Does it work if you add `.doStuff` into the prototype of `Entry` ? Never mind, jQuery doesn't check for `.hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: tldr; Ajax calls any functions in an object when serializing it. If you care why, read on:

This drove me a little crazy, until I managed to follow the stack trace backwards.   It seems the function `doStuff` *was* being called by jquery-1.7.1.js `$.ajax`. But why?

The object in question, "entry" here, has to be serialized into a query string for sending over the network.  In doing so, it goes through each of the object's properties.

First, (on line 7610 for me) it checks if the object `isPlainObject`. It may have been before, but having a function no longer makes it so. Instead, it does the following:

```
jQuery.each( a, function() {
    add( this.name, this.value );
});
```

It defined add just a little earlier, as so:

```
add = function( key, value ) {
    // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
    value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : value;
    s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
};
```

Note the comment jQuery lovingly provided us.  It goes through *every* property of the object, and if one is a function it uses the function's return value as the "value" of the "key/value" pair. It was calling `doStuff` here to get a value (which of course returned `undefined` because the function simply called an alert)

I will add, for my own sake, that the documentation doesn't really make this explicit. I always assumed it ignored functions, but its good to not that it **most certainly does not**.

> **data**  (*Object, String*)
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Finally, through a simple test (not full reading the code), it seems that `JSON.stringify` *does* ignore functions altogether.